# jquery change event keeps firing

Tags: jquery

I have to populate one select box (b) based on another one before (a), I used change event for this, but The change event keeps firing and the second select box keeps on populating itself, this way I am not able to select an item in the second select box, since whatever I select It repopulates itself and I see the very first entry selected in b.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*:first").change(function () {
        var b = document.forms[0].b;
        var a = document.forms[0].a.value;

        if (a != "") {
            var value = "";
            var par = 'c=' + a;

            $.ajax({
                url: "compute",
                data: par,
                type: "post",
                dataType: "text",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    value = JSON.decode(data);
                }
            });

            var options = "";

            for (k in value) {
                options = options + "<option value='" + value[k] + "'>" + k + "</option>" + "\n";
            }

            b.innerHTML = options;
        } else {
            b.innerHTML = '<option value="">-Select-</option>';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try removing the function()?  it will fire once the dom is loaded

Comment: Can we see your HTML that corresponds to the first tag

Comment: Can you post some sample <html> that this happens with?

Comment: `<html:select property="a">
    <option value="" selected>-Select-</option>
    <%fill(out,"a",e,"");%>
    </html:select>`

Comment: <html:select property="b" style="width:100pt;">
     <option value="">-Select-</option>    
    </html:select>

Comment: You should put this in a jsfiddle.

Comment: @wirey; which function()??? How can I write without function(){}

Comment: jsfiddle?!! Don't know about it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net - paste in your html, javascript, css

Comment: Is this not because you are firing :first on both "selects". That way, every time the $(document).ready() is called, you might be running your function above.

Comment: Maybe make the try  $("selectOne:first").change() and  $("selectTwo:first").change() seperately in code, and test to see the result you get.

Comment: @DaneBalia Yea, you are right, :first is selecting both the selects, but isn't it supposed to select only the very first element?

Comment: It will detect a change to every first element of every "select" :)

Comment: oh..k.. Thank you all :) problem solved. Apparently I am very poor with selectors

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** You are correct that `:first` reduces the matched set to only the first item; however `*` matches *everything*, so `*:first` is actually selecting the `<html>` element (or other top-level element in your case). `.change()` is not intended for use with that element, so its default behavior is undefined -- but since *the change event bubbles* up to the top-level element from your `<select>` elements, it seems as if it is being triggered on both of them each time.

**Solution:** Bind your handler to the correct element. Also, don't make the request `async: false`, since this causes the browser to hang until the server responds. Instead, move the other code into the success callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = $('select:last');
    $("select:first").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var a = $this.val();

        if (a) {
            var par = 'c=' + a;
            $.ajax({
                url: "compute",
                data: par,
                type: "post",
                dataType: "text",
                //async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var value = JSON.decode(data);
                    var options = "";
                    for (k in value)
                        options += "<option value='" + value[k] + "'>" + k + "</option>";

                    b.html(options);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            b.html('<option value="">-Select-</option>');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Time for payback bruv! `:)` +1 innit